# Flask-SQLAlchemy– Can you make a query within a model?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm building a flask webapp which uses Flask-SQLAlchemy, and I'm also considering using Flask-Login to take care of sessions and to protect certain views.

Flask-Login requires certain methods which I see as useful for various parts of the app (specifically, `is_authenticated()` and `is_active()`. However, in all of the examples I've seen these methods just return something fixed. What if I want to make a query on the database. For example, if I want to check if that user actually has an entry in the table (I'm using LDAP to log in, so want users to be able to log in even if they haven't got an entry in the table, although I need to see if they are there).

But I don't know if it's possible to make a query on the table itself from within the class which defines it? Or should I place these functions elsewhere (even though the methods are needed by flask-login within the user class)?

Comment: What happens when you try `self.query.filter(your=criteria, goes=here)` in one of your methods? ;-)

Comment: @SeanVieira I pass it one criteria (username=self.username), but it doesn't seem to like it: `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'`

Answer (score 6):

You can. Usually the [`Session.object_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.object_session) is a good way to get a session and perform a query:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'model_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...

    def my_method(self):
       session = Session.object_session(self)
       qry = session.query(...).filter(...)
       # ...
```

Comment: Ahh, that looks about right. I've imported `from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session` and then `session = Session.object_session(self)`. However, session then seems to be `None`. I wonder what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the object (`self`) already added to a session or loaded from the database? If it is a brand new instance and it has not been added to a session(Transient; see [Quickie Intro to Object States](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#quickie-intro-to-object-states)), `object_session` would indeed return `None`. In this case you can always just create a new session; but in web applications often one uses contextual sessions. See [Contextual/Thread-local Sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions) for more information.

Comment: Ah, so because the entry isn't already in the database, and I haven't made a commit, there won't be any session yet. How would I go about creating one within the class, whilst still staying within the spec of the methods I need to use? Because I don't think I'd be able to pass in the bind details in those methods.

Comment: See my comment above about the Contextual/Thread-Local Sessions, but maybe the answer from Miguel is also useful. I do not know anything about Flask and Flast-SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

Flask-Login requires that you provide a user object in the user loader callback. This user does not need to be backed by a database entry, it can be any object as long as it implements the required methods such as `is_authenticated()` and `is_active()`.

From your description it seems to me that the representation of a user that you need is not one that maps one to one to the user table in your database, since you have valid users that are not in your database.

One approach that you can take is to have two user classes, both implementing the required methods. Let's call these `DBUser` and `LDAPUser`. As long as you figure out a strategy to have unique IDs across instances of the two classes Flask-Login will not care.

The `DBUser` class can be a proper database model based on Flask-SQLAlchemy, with straightforward implementations of the `is_xxx()` methods. The `LDAPUser` class, on the other side, can implement these methods issuing any necessary database queries into `DBUser.query`.