# Custom ID Flask Sql Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a custom ID in the table. The ID I want:

1909001
1909002

Basically the format is yymm + counter and I want to do a query to check the last id within the model class. Tried to use code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595226/flask-sqlalchemy-can-you-make-a-query-within-a-model) but still no luck.

```
class Task(db.Model):
    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    request_dt = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    request_detail = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    requestor = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def get_last_id(self):
        ym = date.today().strftime("%y%m")
        qry = self.query.filter(self.task_id.like("{}".format(ym))).order_by(self.task_id.desc()).first()
        if qry.task_id == '':
            return ym + '001'
        else:
            lastid = qry.task_id
            return "{:02d}".format(int(lastid[-3:]) + 1)

    def __init__(self, subject, req_dt, req_detail, reqtor):
        self.task_id = self.get_last_id()
        self.subject = subject
        self.request_detail = req_detail
        self.request_dt = req_dt
        self.requestor = reqtor
```

Comment: What happens if there are 1000+ tasks in a month? Can you elaborate on the problem that you are trying to solve with this structured id field?

Comment: I think it's not gonna happen. Basically I plan to move task assignment in my team from excel to web based. So far max only 10 tasks in a month. And I don't want to change the legacy ID format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you can return the id form task and just add the strings together and zfill the id.

```
def get_last_id():
    qry = Task.query.order_by(Task.id.desc()).first()
    x = qry.id
    ym = date.today().strftime("%y%m")
    q_custom_id = "" + ym + str(x).zfill(3) + ""
    return q_custom_id

# print(Task.get_last_id())
```

I have 3 ID's on the DB, this will print the last one, ID 3 will become:

```
1909003
```

I hope this helps you :P

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small flask app that may help you with your question.

You will get custom id with the same formatting that you trying to get.

[see the table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Two08.png)

```
id  custom_id   subject request_detail  request_dt  request_or  date
3   1909003 subject_3   request_detail_3    request_dt_3    request_or_3    2019-09-15 02:35:19.661868
2   1909002 subject_2   request_detail_2    request_dt_2    request_or_2    2019-09-15 02:35:06.191687
1   1909001 subject_1   request_detail_1    request_dt_1    request_or_1    2019-09-15 02:34:21.406240
```

**app.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, CSRFProtect
from sqlalchemy import desc
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = app.config['SECRET_KEY']

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY = app.config['SECRET_KEY']

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)


class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    custom_id = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    request_detail = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    request_dt = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    request_or = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)


    def get_last_id():

        qry = Task.query.order_by(Task.id.desc()).first()
        x = qry.id
        ym = date.today().strftime("%y%m")
        q_custom_id = "" + ym + str(x).zfill(3) + ""

        return q_custom_id


    def __init__(self, custom_id, subject, request_detail, request_dt, request_or):
        self.custom_id = custom_id
        self.subject = subject
        self.request_detail = request_detail
        self.request_dt = request_dt
        self.request_or = request_or


class TaskForm(FlaskForm):
    subject = StringField(u'subject')
    request_detail = StringField(u'request_detail')
    request_dt = StringField(u'request_dt')
    request_or = StringField(u'request_or')

    submit = SubmitField('Save Post')


@app.route('/')
def id_order_task():
    task_id = Task.query.order_by(Task.date.desc())
    return render_template('index.html', task_id=task_id)


@app.route('/set-task', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def set_task():
    form = TaskForm()
    try:
        get_id = Task.query.order_by(desc('id')).first()
        x: int = get_id.id + 1
        y = date.today().strftime("%y%m")
        if get_id:
            custom_id = "" + y + str(x).zfill(3) + ""
    except:
        custom_id = str(date.today().strftime("%y%m") + str(1).zfill(3))
    finally:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            add_task = Task(
                custom_id=custom_id,
                subject=request.form['subject'],
                request_detail=request.form['request_detail'],
                request_dt=request.form['request_dt'],
                request_or=request.form['request_or']
            )
            db.session.add(add_task)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('id_order_task'))
    return render_template('set-task.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**set-task.html**

```
<div>
    <form action="{{ url_for('set_task') }}" method="post">

        {{ form.csrf_token }}

        {{ form.subject.label }}
        {{ form.subject }}

        {{ form.request_detail.label }}
        {{ form.request_detail }}

        {{ form.request_dt.label }}
        {{ form.request_dt }}

        {{ form.request_or.label }}
        {{ form.request_or }}

        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>

  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>id</th>
           <th>custom_id</th>
           <th>subject</th>
           <th>request_detail</th>
            <th>request_dt</th>
            <th>request_or</th>
            <th>date</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        {% for i in task_id %}
           <tr>
              <td>{{ i.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ i.custom_id}}</td>
              <td>{{ i.subject }}</td>
              <td>{{ i.request_detail }}</td>
           <td>{{ i.request_dt }}</td>
              <td>{{ i.request_or }}</td>
              <td>{{ i.date }}</td>
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi Timm, thanks for your code. It works! But I'm just wondering, can we do the get_id (check the last ID from DB) inside the class Task?

Comment: Hi Bimo, When I do the following Query I get the last custom Id, I believe should be easy to add to your code. `qry = Task.query.order_by(Task.custom_id.desc()).first()
print(qry.custom_id)`